# I need to get the information from every page on the screen

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have a code that works well to recover data from the screen!

My code saves the information of products that are producing on the screen, however, when I finish a list of 10 products on the screen, I need to call to go to the next list and do the same retrieve process as information.

I don't know how to do that ... I only know how to retrieve the information from the first 10 presenter products on the screen.

My code:

````js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs')

let result = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.wavenfe.com.br/');
    await page.type('#logarEmail', 'wave', { delay: 100 })
    await page.type('#logarSenha', '1234', { delay: 100 })
    await page.click('#logar')
    await page.waitForTimeout(1000)
    await page.goto('https://www.wavenfe.com.br/viewria/nfeApplication/simple/produto.html')
    await page.waitForTimeout(3000)
    const list = await page.$$eval("tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1) > span > a", async (element, index) => {
        const produtos = []
        // Use for...of loop:
        for (const elem of element) {
            dados = {}
            elem.click()
            // Add a timeout:
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))
            // Go on:
            dados.nome = document.querySelector('#txtProdDesc').value
            dados.codigo = document.querySelector('#txtProdCodigo').value
            dados.ncm = document.querySelector('#txtProdNCM').value
            dados.unidadeMedida = document.querySelector('#cbProdUnidMedida').value
            dados.icmsSituacaoTributaria = document.querySelector('#cbProdTribICMSSitTrib').value
            dados.icmsOrigem = document.querySelector('#cbProdTribICMSOrigem').value
            dados.pisSituacaoTrib = document.querySelector('#cbProdTribPISSitTrib').value
            dados.cofinsSituacaoTrib = document.querySelector('#cbProdTribCOFINSSitTrib').value
            produtos.push(dados)
        }
        return produtos
    })
    await browser.close();
    return list
}
result().then((value)=>{
    if(fs.existsSync('waveNfe.json')) return console.log(`File exist`)
    fs.writeFile('waveNfe.json', JSON.stringify(value, null, 2), error =>{    
        if(error) throw error
        console.log(`Sucess!`)
    })
})```

I need that after it retrieves the information from the first screen, the system clicks on the second page and retrieves the information from it.

I have no idea how to do it.

Can someone help me? I'm a beginner.
````

Comment: Are you saying that there's pagination for the product? If so, then find a way to get the next list of results. This can be done by either click the next button, editing the url if the pagination is in the url, or if the results are triggered by scrolling to the body, using `page.evaluate(()=>window.scrollBy(window.innerHeight))`

Comment: In my case, I need to click "2" to load the new product list. But how do I do that and then retrieve everyone's information again?

If you can take a look at the URL:

https://www.wavenfe.com.br/viewria/nfeApplication/simple/produto.html

Login: wave
Password: 1234

Comment: I think you’d stay logged in so that wouldn’t be a problem. You just have to convert your ‘page.$$eval’ into a function and concat that to your list. Find a way to target the next page and make a while loop that there’s a next page, click the link, wait for load, and concat your page.$$eval function to list. I can demonstrate when I get off work

Comment: Please! If you can demonstrate me in code, I would be really grateful!

I'm a beginner and this project is precisely in order to learn and take it into practice.

I am very grateful

Comment: Im sorry I cant read the language on the site and I'm not sure how the site works